# AVD's Emulator problem at launch in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-manager, avd-manager

> Emulator (API 29, Android 10.0, CPU x86)

This happens when I launch a device emulator. Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening? Is more info needed?

```
6:57 PM Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize ADC

6:57 PM Emulator: dsound: Could not create capture buffer

6:57 PM Emulator: dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID

6:57 PM Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

6:57 PM Emulator: C:\Users\deus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed

6:57 PM Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize ADC

6:57 PM Emulator: dsound: Could not create capture buffer

6:57 PM Emulator: dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID

6:57 PM Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's your new Windows 10 Update. I couldn't figure it out for the life of me! I looked at 4 pages of results on Google and only saw the same old crap. So, here we go.

To Fix: Click Start, go to ⚙ Settings> Privacy Settings> Microphone. Turn On "Allow apps to access your microphone"

Comment: I tried this but the error messages persist. @Anshul Chauhan

Comment: Try plugging in and plugging out an earphone which has a mic. Maybe it can help. @EliasMarrero